# "Redux is not working properly with login"

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have implemented redux with my login form which is not working properly
it shows ERROR 'Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined. which i think it means that redux is not implemented properly.
Please Help!
if you need any other file,tell me i will share it to you.

LoginForm.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
//StyleSheet,
View,
Text,
TextInput,
Button    
} from 'react-native';
import {reduxForm,Field} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {login} from './authActions';

const validate = values =>{
  const errors = {};
  if(!values.email){
      errors.email="Please fill the email"
      return errors;

  }
  if(!values.password){
    errors.password="Please fill the password"
    return errors;

  }
}

const myFields = ({label,meta:{error,touched}, input:{onChange}}) =>{
  return(
      <View>
        <Text>{label}</Text>
        <TextInput style={{borderWidth:1,width:300,marginBottom:10}}            
        onChangeText={onChange}/>
        {touched && (error && (<Text style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</Text>))}
      </View>
  );
}

const passFields = ({label,meta:{error,touched}, input:{onChange}}) =>{
return(
    <View>
      <Text>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput style={{borderWidth:1,width:300,marginBottom:10}}
      secureTextEntry={true}        
      onChangeText={onChange}/>
      {touched && (error && (<Text style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</Text>))}
    </View>
  );
  }


 const submitbtn = values =>{
  //alert(`here are the values ${JSON.stringify(values)}`);
  //console.log(input.value);
  this.props.login(values);

  }

  const myLoginForm = props => {
  const {handleSubmit} = props;
  return(
    <View>
        <Field
        name="email"           
        component={myFields}
        label="Email"/>

        <Field
        name="password"           
        component={passFields}
        label="Password"
       />

        <Button title="Submit"
        onPress={handleSubmit(submitbtn)}/>

    </View>
   );
  }

  const LoginForm = reduxForm({
  form:'loginform',
  validate
  })(myLoginForm);

 const mapStateToProps =(state) =>({
 isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
 });

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{login})(LoginForm);
```

authActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
//import { returnErrors } from './errorActions';

export const register = ({username, name, email, password}) => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'Application/json'
            }
        }

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            username,
            name,
            email,
            password
        })

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/register', body , config )
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type : 'REGISTER_SUCCESS',
            payload : res.data 
        }))
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'));
            dispatch({
                type : 'REGISTER_FAIL'
            })
        });
    };
};

export const login = ({username, password}) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'Application/json'
            }
        }

        const body = JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        })

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', body , config )
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type : 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
            payload : res.data 
        }))
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
            dispatch({
                type : 'LOGIN_FAIL'
            })
        });
    };
}

export const logout = () => {
    return {
        type : 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS'
    }
}

export const loadUser = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'USER_LOADING',
        });

        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/auth' , tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: 'USER_LOADED',
            payload : res.data
        }))
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data.message, err.response.status));
            dispatch({
                type : 'AUTH_ERROR'
            });
        })
    }
}


//
export const tokenConfig = (getState) => {

    const token = getState().auth.token;

    const config = {
        headers : {
            'content-type' : 'Application/json',
        }
    }

    if(token) {
        config.headers['auth'] = token;
    }

    return config;
}
```

authReducer.js

```
const initState = {
    toke: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: null,
    user: null
};

const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'USER_LOADING':
        return{
            ...state,
            isLoading: true
        }
        case 'USER_LOADED':
        return{
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            isAuthenticated:true,
            user:action.payload
        }
        case 'REGISTER_SUCCESS':
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token)
        return{
            ...state,
            ...action.payload,
            isLoading: false,
            isAuthenticated:true,            
        }
        case 'AUTH_ERROR':
        case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
        case 'LOGIN_FAIL':
        case 'REGISTER_FAIL':        
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
        return{
            token: null,
            user: null,
            isLoading: false,
            isAuthenticated:false,            
        }
        default:
            return state;


    }
}
export default authReducer
```

Comment: this means that on LoginForm.js when you are getting the isAuthenticated on mapStateToProps the state.auth is undefined. You must see when you combined the reducers what name you gave to the auth reducer? do a console log there and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check file where you combine your reducers, there's possibility that you put your reducer as something other than "auth" or even you forgotten to put the reducer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install "redux-devtools-extension" package and it's chrome extension to see which reducers are connected to your redux state and debug it more easily. Also, redux-form requires you to pass the form reducer you create along with all the other reducers you have in 'combineReducers'. Follow the instructions on their docs https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/

hope this helps :)